# How to join two line geometries together into a single record?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have a series of lines that I need to join together into a single record. Bellow is a mockup representation of my data. Some section numbers are duplicated and I need to update the geometries of the same section number into a single record.

Mockup Data:

| id | section | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 1234 |
| 2 | 32 | 1213 |
| 3 | 32 | 1231 |
| 4 | 33 | 3121 |

What I need:

| id | section | geom |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 1234,1213,1231 |
| 4 | 33 | 3121 |

From what I have read ST_union is a good way to to this but can figure out how to update the rows. I think I need to subquery an update query but am unsure how to format this.

Sample Code:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE "tlbsections"
SELECT section,
       ST_Union(geom) as singlegeom
FROM "Ecorys_alkmaar_sections"
WHERE section = '32'
GROUP BY section
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to do it

1. Insert union records into new table using below query  -

```
insert into Ecorys_alkmaar_sections_1 (id,section,geom)
select min(id),section,ST_UNION(geom) as shape 
from Ecorys_alkmaar_sections
group by section
```

```
 Output of the above query will be -
```

[image]

2. Update the existing table and delete duplicate records

You can use the below code to do the update based on the join condition

```
update Ecorys_alkmaar_sections t1
set geom = t2.geom 
from (select section,ST_UNION(geom) as shape 
from Ecorys_alkmaar_sections
group by section) t2 
where t1.section=t2.section
```

the output of the above command will be  -

[image]

so you need to delete the duplicate records once the update is done.